# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar la traducción de cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Buen día, tengo este fragmento de código:

```
 $this->Flash->success('Reset password link has been sent to your email ('.$myemail.'), please open your inbox');
```

es un mensaje que aparece por pantalla, una vez que el usuario solicita restablecer su contraseña.

$myemail es la variable que guarda el email que se ingresa.

Este es el código que utilizo para la tradición en mi archivo .po

```
msgid "Reset password link has been sent to your email ('.$myemail.'), please open your inbox"
msgstr "El enlace para restablecer la contraseña se ha enviado a su correo electrónico ('.$myemail.'), abra su bandeja de entrada"
```

Estoy utilizando cakephp, como fremawork.
de la manera en que lo estoy haciendo, el mensaje no es traducido. Quizás por tener un variable concatenada en dicho mensaje.
¿Tienen alguna idea de como debo corregirlo?

Comment: que dice la documentacion de cakephp al respecto???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo realicé de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->Flash->success(__('A link to reset your password was sent, please check your inbox')." ". "$myemail");
```

coloqué primero el mensaje y luego concateno la variable que muestra el correo al cual se envía el mensaje, de esta forma la variable queda fuera del mensaje a traducir y no causa problemas para su traducción.
el código en el archivo.po queda de está manera:

```
msgid "A link to reset your password was sent, please check your inbox"
msgstr "Se envió un enlace para restablecer su contraseña, por favor verifique su bandeja de entrada"
```

aquí ya no coloco la variable, como lo hacia antes. De esta manera me funciona bien.

**Nota:** *Igualmente hay otras formas de clocar las variables al momento de hacer estas traducciones, se debe consultar un poco mas la documentación.*